# Sorting and indexing multiple conditions in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is a simple sample of my data:

[image]

I want to get the outcome. The logic is that we have 4 pairs data highlighted in different colours.

I want to get the outcome as follows.
If both colours are "Y", I would aggregate them. For example, in row 2, the green has a value of "Y" ( both have "Y", so we could get 1 in the outcome) In Row 3, yellow and orange have  a value of "Y", so we get a value of 2 in outcome.

I have tried the following function, but it did not work for me.

```
IF(OR(AND(A2="N", B2="N"), AND(C2="N", D2="N"),AND(E2="N", F2="N"),AND(G2="N", H2="N")), "0", "1")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `I2`, using Excel O365:

```
=SUM((INDEX(A2:H2,{1,3,5,7})="Y")*(INDEX(A2:H2,{2,4,6,8})="Y"))
```

In Excel prior to Excel O365, try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX(A2:H2,N(IF(1,{1,3,5,7})))="Y")*(INDEX(A2:H2,N(IF(1,{2,4,6,8})))="Y"))
```

Comment: @user330, I'm not following. This gets you the desired results doesn't it? Can you explain what you meant with "Can we do it better?"

Comment: I've shown a screenshot of my results @user330.

Comment: Thanks, I exactly copy-pasted your codes, but still, I get 0, 1. I use Excel 2016

Comment: @JvdV  This is a version thing.  If you want to use INDEX in the older version like you have it needs to be:  `=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX(A2:H2,IF({1},{1,3,5,7}))="Y")*(INDEX(A2:H2,IF({1},{2,4,6,8}))="Y"))` And may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Thanks, Scott, Unfortunately,this gives me the sam results , i.e., 0, 1

Comment: @ScottCraner you are right though. I've updated my answer. I tried in Excel 2016 and no CSE needed using `SUMPRODUCT()`. Note the slight difference on his suggestion and mine using `N()`.

Comment: @user330 Use the one in the edit above by JvdV.  Tested and works.